# Install JSR-82 on eclipse

Tags: java, api, bluetooth, installation

I'm using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
And I just want to run this piece of program but I just can't :/

```
import javax.bluetooth.*;
import javax.microedition.io.*;
import com.atinav.BCC;

public class WirelessDevice implements DiscoveryListener {
LocalDevice localDevice = null; 

public WirelessDevice (){ 
    //setting the port number using Atinav's BCC
    BCC.setPortName("COM1"); 

    //setting the baud rate using Atinav's BCC
    BCC.setBaudRate(57600);

    //connectable mode using Atinav's BCC
    BCC.setConnectable(true);

    //Set discoverable mode using Atinav's BCC 
    BCC.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC); 

    try{
        localDevice = LocalDevice.getLoaclDevice(); 
    }
    catch (BluetoothStateException exp) {
    }

    // implementation of methods in DiscoveryListener class
    // of javax.bluetooth goes here

    // now do some work
}



}
```

I installed JME Wireless Toolkit 2.2 but this is not what I'm looking for.

I just want that my program in Java does a connection with a Bluetooth device.

So can someone explain how to install the javax.bluetooth API which is included in the jsr-82 ?

Comment: Do you want connection between mobiles? using j2me?

Comment: No its not for mobile. This program is suppose to make a Bluetooth connection with a radar (PC <-> Radar) and then get all the information of the radar with the right request. But now I can use javax.bluetooth, I installed bluecove. But the problem now is I understand nothing :/ What are the step to respect to do a correct connection ? Do you have a good tutoriel for me ?

Comment: http://bluecove.org/bluecove-examples/index.html You can download the examples from the site and test it. Also you can get a example in j2me for RFCOMM bluetooth connection, The code is same for that